# Python AWS Cognito authenticate to other user pool as in Javascript

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I do not have a lot of experience with AWS Cognito. In Javascript, I can authenticate with other user's pool using below code:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import { CognitoUserPool, CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

export async function getJwtToken() {
  const UserPoolId = process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID;
  const ClientId = process.env.COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID;
  const Username = process.env.COGNITO_USERNAME;
  const Password = process.env.COGNITO_PASSWORD;
  const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId,
    ClientId
  });

  const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
    Username,
    Pool: userPool
  });

  const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
    Username,
    Password
  });

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: function (result) {
        const token = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
        resolve(token);
      },
      onFailure: function (err) {
        console.error('Error obtaining JWT token:', err);
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

But in Python, I need `cognito_idp_client` for authenticating. I refer to this code [github link](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/cognito/cognito_idp_actions.py#L187)

```
def start_sign_in(self, user_name, password):
    """
    Starts the sign-in process for a user by using administrator credentials.
    This method of signing in is appropriate for code running on a secure server.

    If the user pool is configured to require MFA and this is the first sign-in
    for the user, Amazon Cognito returns a challenge response to set up an
    MFA application. When this occurs, this function gets an MFA secret from
    Amazon Cognito and returns it to the caller.

    :param user_name: The name of the user to sign in.
    :param password: The user's password.
    :return: The result of the sign-in attempt. When sign-in is successful, this
             returns an access token that can be used to get AWS credentials. Otherwise,
             Amazon Cognito returns a challenge to set up an MFA application,
             or a challenge to enter an MFA code from a registered MFA application.
    """
    try:
        kwargs = {
            "UserPoolId": self.user_pool_id,
            "ClientId": self.client_id,
            "AuthFlow": "ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
            "AuthParameters": {"USERNAME": user_name, "PASSWORD": password},
        }
        if self.client_secret is not None:
            kwargs["AuthParameters"]["SECRET_HASH"] = self._secret_hash(user_name)
        response = self.cognito_idp_client.admin_initiate_auth(**kwargs)
        challenge_name = response.get("ChallengeName", None)
        if challenge_name == "MFA_SETUP":
            if (
                "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA"
                in response["ChallengeParameters"]["MFAS_CAN_SETUP"]
            ):
                response.update(self.get_mfa_secret(response["Session"]))
            else:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    "The user pool requires MFA setup, but the user pool is not "
                    "configured for TOTP MFA. This example requires TOTP MFA."
                )
    except ClientError as err:
        logger.error(
            "Couldn't start sign in for %s. Here's why: %s: %s",
            user_name,
            err.response["Error"]["Code"],
            err.response["Error"]["Message"],
        )
        raise
    else:
        response.pop("ResponseMetadata", None)
        return response
```

Without cognito_idp_client, Python authentication do not work. I can create my own cognito_idp_client using below code:

```
cognito_client = boto3.client(
'cognito-idp',
aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY'),
aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_KEY'),
region_name=os.environ.get('AWS_REGION'),
```

)

But it will not work because user_pool_id is not my AWS Cognito. Is it possible to achieve results as in Javascript? Authenticating to another service user pool?

Comment: Probably it is not even possible as Google Gemini suggest and based on my own research